# 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeFile')' error while trying to write to a file with REACT

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to write to a file with a button click inside my React application and it gives an error.

My current code looks like this.

```
import {fs} from "fs"


function App() {

async function syncItems(){

  console.log("Sync start test")   // This line prints

  fs.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hey there!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The file was saved!");
});

  console.log("Sync end test")   / This line doesn’t print
  }


return (
<Button color="success" onClick={() => { syncItems(); }}> Sync </Button>
);


}
```

Once I click the **SYNC** button it gives this error. This might be a noob mistake since I am new to this. I'd really appreciate if someone could help.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'writeFile')
    at syncItems (App.js:54:1)
    at Object.onClick (App.js:189:1)
    at Button.onClick (Button.js:42:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:8508:1
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22396:1)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3745:1)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:8507:1)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6005:1)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5924:1)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22413:1)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756:1)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889:1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import statement is incorrect.

You can either import `fs` entire module:

```
import fs from 'fs';
fs.writeFile(/*...*/);
```

Or import a function from the module:

```
import { writeFile } from 'fs';
writeFile(/*...*/)
```

Note that your code will not produce the desired output because `fs.writeFile` is an asynchronous function, which callback only gets executed once the operation completed. So this is what is going to be printed:

> Sync start test
> Sync end test
> The file was saved!

Since you are in an async function, I would recommend using `fs.promises.writeFile`:

```
async function syncItems(){
  console.log("Sync start test");
  await fs.promises.writeFile("/tmp/test", "Hey there!")
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err) });
  console.log("The file was saved!");
  console.log("Sync end test")
  return (
    <Button color="success" onClick={() => { syncItems(); }}> Sync </Button>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried this, then it gives this error.

```
App.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9___default.a.writeFile is not a function


    at Module.<anonymous> (App.js:19:1)
    at Module../src/App.js (App.js:231:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (Web3Client.js:109:1)
    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:8:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Object.1 (index.js:8:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:851:1)
```

Comment: You can find the whole file from here : https://github.com/sandxru/VaxPass/blob/master/Blockchain/src/App.js

Comment: Ahh but this is frontend code! You cannot use NodeJS APIs in code that runs in the browser and the browser does not have access to the file system. If you wish to save a file on your server, you have to send it to an endpoint of your web server and then, save it on the server file system. That's not code short enough to be provided in a SO answer.

Comment: Thank @ Ben for letting me know. My initial goal is to save data to a MySQL db. Tried multiple days but didn’t work. So I give try to write it to a file. I opened a new thread for the MySQL thing. If you could have a look I'd really appreciate that. Thank you!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71627616/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-query-error-while-trying-to-conn